# What is the Swift equivalency of NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE?

Tags: swift3, uistoryboardsegue

Scenario:

I'm translating an Objective-C sample code supplied by Apple into Swift 3.0.1.

I came across some code that requires the need to prevent the presentationController from being released prior to calling preventViewController. Hence the use of NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE (see image below).

[image]

What's the best alternative using Swift?

...without it... all I get is a nil for the **transitioningDelegate** value upon access soon afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is using [`withExtendedLifetime(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541033-withextendedlifetime):

```
override func perform() {
    let sourceViewController = self.destination
    let destinationViewController = self.destination

    // For presentations which will use a custom presentation controller,
    // it is possible for that presentation controller to also be the
    // transitioningDelegate.
    //
    // transitioningDelegate does not hold a strong reference to its
    // destination object.  To prevent presentationController from being
    // released prior to calling -presentViewController:animated:completion:
    // the NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE attribute is appended to the declaration.

    let presentationController = AAPLAdaptivePresentationController(presentedViewController: destinationViewController, presenting: sourceViewController)

    withExtendedLifetime(presentationController) {

        destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = presentationController

        self.source.present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

Or else, this would work in the case shown in the picture:

```
override func perform() {
    let sourceViewController = self.destination
    let destinationViewController = self.destination

    // For presentations which will use a custom presentation controller,
    // it is possible for that presentation controller to also be the
    // transitioningDelegate.
    //
    // transitioningDelegate does not hold a strong reference to its
    // destination object.  To prevent presentationController from being
    // released prior to calling -presentViewController:animated:completion:
    // the NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE attribute is appended to the declaration.

    let presentationController = AAPLAdaptivePresentationController(presentedViewController: destinationViewController, presenting: sourceViewController)

    destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate = presentationController

    self.source.present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        let _ = presentationController  //<- having a strong reference in the completion handler
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to extend the life of target entity.  That is,  the segue apparently looses its assets prior to the instantiation of the destinationViewController.  The destinationViewController.transitioningDelegate is still nil when attempting to access it once control reaches the VC's iVar.

Comment: I would be careful with compiler optimization making it look like everything works fine in Debug and not working in production due to the fact that the useless variable was removed by compiler...